# Android insert contact activity does not finish when press save button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, addressbook, onactivityresult

My problem is that when I call system activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_CONTACT_ACTIVITY);
```

to insert a new contact in my addressbook, when I press Save button, the activity does not finish spontaneously but I must press device back button.

What can I do to end it spontaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `finish()` to terminate immediatly the activity where it is called.

Comment: Using `finish()` I can terminate my activity, but if I want finish system activity started from my app (in my case addressbook activity) ?